# How move all commits from specific user to a new branch?

Tags: git, branch, commit

I have 'commits' from many users. I want to move all commits of some user to a new branch.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Find all commits by one author and save their hash to a file:

```
git log --author=<author> --format=%H > /tmp/commit-by-x
```

Create a new branch that does not contain this particular's author commit since you don't want to apply them twice. For this, you can create a new empty branch:

```
git checkout --orphan commits-by-x
```

Cherry-pick all commits of that author (from oldest to newest):

```
tac /tmp/commit-by-x | while read sha; do git cherry-pick ${sha}; done
```

Obviously, if you want this to succeed the changes introduced by author-x have to be very localized.

Comment: Great solution!  Instead of using --orphan, I had more success using git checkout -b <new branch name> at that step, and I modified the tmp file so that it only contained the most recent dozen or so commits by the specific author.  As mentioned, this won't work easily if the author's commits are spread across multiple branches, so you may need to select only certain hashes from the tmp file after it is generated by the first command.